# Moq method call sequence comparison

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

In a xUnit test, I would like to compare method calls (sequence and values) between a reference class and the tested class, that calls a mocked class.

For example :

```
public interface ITarget
{
    void A(string val);
    void B(int val);
}

public class RefClass
{
    private readonly ITarget m_target;
    public RefClass(ITarget target) { this.m_target = target; }
    public void Work()
    {
        this.m_target.A("A");
        this.m_target.A("B");
        this.m_target.B(0);
        this.m_target.B(1);
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    private readonly ITarget m_target;
    public TestClass(ITarget target) { this.m_target = target; }
    public void Work()
    {
        this.m_target.A("B");
        this.m_target.B(1);
        this.m_target.B(0);
        this.m_target.A("A");
    }
}

public class WorkTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void Work_is_done_in_sequence()
    {
        var refTarget = new Mock<ITarget>();
        var refClass = new RefClass(refTarget.Object);
        refClass.Work();

        var testTarget = new Mock<ITarget>();
        var testClass = new TestClass(testTarget.Object);
        testClass.Work();

        //TODO : compare refTarget and testTarget method call sequence
    }
}
```

How can I compare that the tested class use the target interface exactly the same way the reference class does ? Thanks.

Comment: By setting up the same expected behavior of the mocks and verifying them and exercising the methods under test. And since you have not shown how the mock is being used there isn't much we can tell you on how to do that. provide a [mcve] that can be used to properly represent what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: You could even setup one mock and reuse it in the target classes. you can then verify that the same expected behavior is executed twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to validate the sequence of calls using predefined values, you can use `MockSequence`. **Note** - you need to use strict mocks. The test will fail on `sut.Do()`, no need of assertions:

```
public void TEST()
{
    //arrange
    var mock = new Mock<ITarget>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var seq = new MockSequence();
    mock.InSequence(seq).Setup(m => m.A("A1"));
    mock.InSequence(seq).Setup(m => m.A("A2"));
    mock.InSequence(seq).Setup(m => m.B("B1"));
    mock.InSequence(seq).Setup(m => m.B("B2"));

    var sut = new Sut(mock.Object);

    //act
    sut.Do();
 }
```

If you do not want to go that route, you may setup your mock with a callback, and add the parameters in some list:

```
[Test]
public void TEST()
{
    //arrange
    var mock = new Mock<ITarget>();
    var calls = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.A(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Callback<string>(s => calls.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("A", s)));
    mock.Setup(m => m.B(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Callback<string>(s => calls.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("B", s)));

    var sut = new Sut(mock.Object);

    //act
    sut.Do();

    //assert
    //inspect calls
}
```

P.S. I would test the two classes in 2 separated tests.

Comment: At the end, I did something like the second solution, with a StringBuilder.

Comment: "you need to use strict mocks" - thank you so much for that

Answer (score 0):

> How can I compare that the tested class use the target interface
>   exactly the same way the reference class does ?

By setting up the same expected behavior of the mocks and verifying them after exercising the methods under test.

You could even setup one mock and reuse it in the target classes. you can then verify that the same expected behavior is executed twice.

```
[Fact]
public void Work_is_done_in_sequence() {
    //Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<ITarget>();
    var refClass = new RefClass(mock.Object);
    var testClass = new TestClass(mock.Object);

    //Act
    refClass.Work();
    testClass.Work();

    //Assert
    var expected_A_Val = "some_value";
    mock.Verify(_ => _.A(expected_A_Val), Times.Exactly(2));

    var expected_B_Val = 3;
    mock.Verify(_ => _.B(expected_B_Val), Times.Exactly(2));        
}
```

Comment: This would be nice if there were a few calls to ITarget methods, since you have to write them one by one. The sample is drastically cut down since real implementation make a hundred calls to ITarget class, that is why I am asking if it is possible to compare the tested class to a reference.